# How to reformat date data in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My input dataframe is

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Source':['Pre-Nov 2017', 'Pre-Nov 2017', 'Oct 19', '2019-04-01 00:00:00', '2019-06-01 00:00:00', 'Nov 17-Nov 18', 'Nov 17-Nov 18']})
```

I would need Target column as below

[image]

If I use the below code , it's not working. I'm getting the same values of Source in the Target column.

```
df['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Source'], format= '%b %Y',errors='ignore')
```

Looks like pandas is considering values like '2019-04-01 00:00:00', '2019-06-01 00:00:00' as NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is use `errors='coerce'` for missing values if not matching datetimes, then convert to custom strings by [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) - also `NaT` are strings, so for replace to original use [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['Target'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['Source'], errors='coerce')
                  .dt.strftime('%b %y')
                  .mask(lambda x: x == 'NaT', df['Source']))
print (df)

                Source         Target
0         Pre-Nov 2017   Pre-Nov 2017
1         Pre-Nov 2017   Pre-Nov 2017
2               Oct 19         Oct 19
3  2019-04-01 00:00:00         Apr 19
4  2019-06-01 00:00:00         Jun 19
5        Nov 17-Nov 18  Nov 17-Nov 18
6        Nov 17-Nov 18  Nov 17-Nov 18
```

Alternative is use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['Source'], errors='coerce')
df['Target'] = np.where(d.isna(), df['Source'], d.dt.strftime('%b %y'))
```

EDIT:

> but why did this did not worked
>
> df['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Source'], format= '%b %Y',errors='ignore')

If check [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)  and use `errors='ignore'` it return same values of column if converting failed.

> If **'ignore'**, then invalid parsing will return the input

Comment: @jezrael but why did this did not worked `df['Target'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Source'], format= '%b %Y',errors='ignore')` ?

Comment: @vb_rises - added to answer, because in my opinion really nice question